# Deploy a Flutter web application on Raspberry LAMP server

Tags: flutter, web-applications, raspberry-pi

I’ve created a LAMP server on my raspberry pi, thinking to develop a Flutter web application on it. I started with the Flutter demo project and build it with the “web” option. Then I’ve transfered the content of created “web” folder to /var/www/html/ on my raspberry pi. But all I can get is a blank page when I open the webapp on my browser. I’m novice in web developing and I’m missing something. Any suggestions? I need to install on LAMP some engine?

Answer (score 0):

LAMP = Linux, Apache, Mysql, PHP/Python/Perl ...

Now Releasing a flutter app is quite different. (see https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/web) but is same as Angular or React. You have to `build` it for web. Like convert dart code to Javascript, html, css.

It should have this directory structure:

```
/build/web
  assets
    AssetManifest.json
    FontManifest.json
    NOTICES
    fonts
      MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf
      <other font files>
    <image files>
  index.html
  main.dart.js
  main.dart.js.map
```

Now, since you have LAMP, You only need Apache for running this.
If you upload /build/web to  /var/www/html/

then you can access it as http://SERVERIP/build/web/

But if you upload contents of /build/web directly on /var/www/html/ then there is no need to look for subdirs.

`/build/web/index.html` should be in `/var/www/html/index.html`

Comment: Yes I know it and that's the problem: if I open http://SERVERIP (I've uploaded contents of /build/web directly on /var/www/html/) I get a blank page.

Comment: Check console for errors

Comment: In the console I have actually an error:

GET http://mysite/main.dart.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
loadMainDartJs @ (index):47
(anonymous) @ (index):97

index 47 is the line document.body.append(scriptTag);
index 97 is the line loadMainDartJs();

In any case, is the procedure to put the content of /build/web directly on /var/www/html/ folder correc without install other package?

Comment: You should have inside /var/www/html at least  `index.html
  main.dart.js
  main.dart.js.map` plus assets if any

Comment: `GET mysite/main.dart.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`  means there is no `main.dart.js` inside `/var/www/html `